# Multiple empty Excel VBA projects

Tags: excel, vba, vbe

Excel generates multiple empty projects (cannot be expanded with "+") as soon as I open the VBA editor.

Every time I close/reopen the editor, new projects add to the pile.

How do I counter this?

This is a RDS (Windows server 2016 Datacenter), using Excel 2013.

[image: Multiple empty projects]

Comment: does this happen if you open Excel-Workbooks manually or when you create a new Workbook with vba?

Comment: When I simply open Excel manually. I also tried disabling all kinds of Excel/COM add-ins, no luck

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me as well. Finally, Excel startup folder C:\Users\YourName\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\ contained some unknown xlsb file (not really sure how I got it), which I deleted. In addition, I deleted Excel15.xlb and personal.xlsb files (deleting these two files might not be necessary). It worked for me.
Best regards,
Ales